# Physics circle collisions popping and sliding against bounds

Tags: java, physics, collision

In Java, I'm writing a mobile app for Android to interact with some dynamic balls with some classes I wrote myself. Gravity is determined on the tilt of the phone.

I noticed when I have a bunch of balls bunched up in a corner that some of them will begin to jitter, or sometimes slide while colliding with other balls. Could this be because I'm executing steps in the wrong order?

Right now I have a single loop going through each ball to:

- Sim an iteration
- Check collisions with other balls
- Check collisions against scene bounds

I should add that I have friction with the bounds and when a ball to ball collision occurs, just to lose energy.

Here's a portion of code of how collision is being handled:

```
    // Sim an iteration
    for (Ball ball : balls) {
        ball.gravity.set(gravity.x, gravity.y);

        if (ball.active) {
            ball.sim();

            // Collide against other balls
            for (Ball otherBall : balls) {
                if (ball != otherBall) {
                    double dist = ball.pos.distance(otherBall.pos);
                    boolean isColliding = dist < ball.radius + otherBall.radius;
                    if (isColliding) {
                        // Offset so they aren't touching anymore
                        MVector dif = otherBall.pos.copy();
                        dif.sub(ball.pos);
                        dif.normalize();
                        double difValue = dist - (ball.radius + otherBall.radius);
                        dif.mult(difValue);
                        ball.pos.add(dif);

                    // Change this velocity
                    double mag = ball.vel.mag();
                    MVector newVel = ball.pos.copy();
                    newVel.sub(otherBall.pos);
                    newVel.normalize();
                    newVel.mult(mag * 0.9);
                    ball.vel = newVel;

                    // Change other velocity
                    double otherMag = otherBall.vel.mag();
                    MVector newOtherVel = otherBall.pos.copy();
                    newOtherVel.sub(ball.pos);
                    newOtherVel.normalize();
                    newOtherVel.mult(otherMag * 0.9);
                    otherBall.vel = newOtherVel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see what you have done so far?

Comment: Do you test in your collision test if the two objects move towards each other? Do you compute exact collision times or do you allow the objects to move into each other?

Comment: Updated with some code. I don't test if two objects are moving towards each other. Right now I allow the balls to move into each other then handle collision.

Comment: I think gravity makes it go out of bounds, then it calculates if any other ball is colliding (which it isn't), then pops back inside the screen boundaries. I have a feeling this is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Jittering in static configurations is a very common problem with physics engines. It's usually handled with heuristics like "if the velocity and acceleration (net force) of the object are very low and the penetration is slight, then set acceleration and velocity to zero and ignore the penetration.

Comment: @Gene This sounds like a good idea, but there's one thing I'm struggling with. If there was a ball that started with no velocity, wouldn't it always zero out when trying to add gravity since it would be increasing too slowly?

Comment: @GreenCell That's why the predicate includes "and net force is very low".  Even if the ball is not moving, if it's accelerating rapidly, you don't reset its velocity.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the only code that checks for interactions between balls, then the problem seems pretty clear.  There is no way for a ball to rest atop another ball, in equilibrium.

Let's say that you have one ball directly on top of another.  When you compute the acceleration of the top ball due to gravity, you should also be doing a collision check like the one you posted, except this time checking for `dist <= ball.radius + otherBall.radius`.  If this is the case, then you should assume a normal force between the balls equal to that of gravity, and negate the component of gravity in line with the vector connecting the two balls' centers.  If you fail to do this, then the top ball will accelerate into the bottom one, triggering the collision code you posted, and you'll get the jitters.

Similar logic must be used when a ball is in contact with a scene bound.

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at, but I'm having trouble figuring out the collision response. So let's say I have `ball1` on top of `ball2`. Prior to simming `ball1`, I test it against `ball2` to see if they're already touching. If they are, I need to adjust `ball1`'s position and adjust gravity's direction so that it doesn't go through it?

Comment: Your adjustment of position is fine; it is the gravity that you need to adjust, as it would be opposed by the normal force between the two balls.  So if ball1 is touching ball2, and the vector dot product of ball1's gravity (g) with the vector (v) pointing from ball1 to ball2 is positive, then you want to subtract from ball1's gravity vector v times (g dot v) / v^2).  That's the component of the gravity vector that is in the direction of v.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've been experimenting with my own Phys2D engine (just for fun), I know you're talking about. (Just in case - you may check my demo here: http://gwt-dynamic-host.appspot.com/ - select "Circle Collisions Demo" there, and corresponding code here: https://github.com/domax/gwt-dynamic-plugins/tree/master/gwt-dynamic-main/gwt-dynamic-module-bar).

The problem is in a nature of iterations and infinite loop of colliding consequences. When e.g. ball is reached the scene corner, it experiences at least 3 vectors of force: impulse of bounce from the wall, impulse of bounce from the floor and impulse of gravity - after you summarize all 3 impulses, reduce it according loosing energy algorithm, you have to have the new vector where your ball should be. But, e.g. this impulse directs it into wall - then you have to recompute the set of vectors again according to all the stuff: energy of bounce, impulses, gravity, etc. Even in case if all these impulses are small, you never get all of them 0, because of precision of doubles and your tolerance comparison constants - that because you have the "jitter" and "sliding" effects.

Actually, most of existing 2D engines have these effects one kind or another: you may see them here: http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#wreckingBall or here: http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html - they actually just make the small impulses to be absorbed faster and stop iterating when the whole system becomes more or less stable, but it is not always possible.

Anyway, I'd just recommend do not reinvent your own wheel unless it is just for your fun - or for your better understanding this stuff.

For last one (JFF) - here is good tutorial: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331

For real things, I'd recommend to use the existing engines, e.g. Unity (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/physics2d) or Box2d (http://box2d.org/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the references! I'll start digging into them.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through all the balls and changing the balls position for each iteration is probably the cause for the instability, you move a ball left to avoid collision on the right, and then you pushed the ball into another ball on the left, and then the left ball tries to push it back again.

From the top of my head I could recommend trying to sum up all the forces on each ball before doing anything about positioning. And if you iterate from the ball "on top" (furthest away from gravity source/direction) you can probably achieve a stable situation.

Basically, the top ball needs to first calculate forces between itself and the ball(s) under it, plus gravity, then the ball under will know how much force is coming from the top ball, and added with gravity it would also add to the force of which it is pushing the balls under it. When all balls know the forces they're pushed with you can transform that force into motion.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are simulating the physics of the balls is bound to cause  instabilities. Your collision resolution tries to separate the balls by   projecting one of them in the opposite direction by the collision depth. This may fix the overlap for those two balls but chances are(especially when the   balls are stacked) that the ball is now overlapping with another ball.

There are many ways to fix penetration. One of the simplest ways is to add a "bias" or a bit of   a push to both bodies to force them to separate over the next couple of frames. This allows that energy to propagate and force all of the bodies apart. Problem   is, the bias will often overestimate and cause a bit of a bounce. To fix that   problem I'd recommend reading up on sequential impulse.

Making physics look realistic is not as easy as it may seem. Unless you   don't mind instabilities I'd recommend spending some time reading up on   different techniques or using an engine such as Box2D.

Comment: I agree, I need to push both instead of just the one. Wouldn't pushing both still have a possibility of both of them overlapping other balls? I'm wondering if I should first solve balls that are closest to the bounds and work its way towards the center. I'll read up more on what you mentioned, this seems to be very tough!

Comment: @GreenCell The bias isn't a projection. It is an applied force to both of the bodies. This means that when the next impulse resolution pass comes, the energy will propagate. I'm assuming you are using impulse resolution. If you're not I'd recommend reading up on it.